# Are images with non-standard extensions (such as ".ashx", instead of ".png" or ".jpg") bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, google-search, cms, images

Certain CMS' running on [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) like [Sitecore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Proprietary_software) do not give image files appropriate file formats like `.png` or `.jpg` by default, but instead link to images as:

```
<img src="/media/Some Folder/EX-IMG.ashx" alt="Example" />
```

Ignoring the spaces, non-descriptive filename, and capitals (likely to break and/or cause duplicate content issues), does that URI with `.ashx` pose a problem?

Is using the correct image file format a ranking factor in organic search **for the page that the image appears on**, or is having a decent alt attribute enough?

(Note, it is not necessary to have this image rank in Google Images, but inform spiders that it is relevant and contextual media related to the text content on the page.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question: no, it should not pose a problem for SEO.

Why not - given that `ashx` has nothing to do with images, you ask? Because of the `MIME type` being sent with the file header.

The `.png` file ending is actually not what determine what the browser has to interpret, but rather the file headers of the HTTP request. The file headers sent when the browser is requesting an image file of type `.png` from the CMS, contain the `MIME type media/png` and the `.ashx` extension is thus, irrelevant. Same goes for HTML files - they can be called `.baumr`, as long as the `MIME type` is `text/html`. This can easily be set up in both Apache and IIS.

The URL example you have used, is not too common. As you mentioned, in a good setup it should be descriptive, solely for SEO/Image search purposes: `/images.ashx?id=picture-of-an-elf`

Comment: Yeah, non-standard image extensions are fine.

Comment: Better yet, use no extensions at all :) `/images?id=picture-of-an-elf` or `/images/picture-of-an-elf` (which runs `index.ashx` and passes in `picture-of-an-elf`) That way you can change your technology without having an identity crisis with your URLs!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the "type of" file requested from the server (as would seem to be suggested by the file ".ashx" extension) , the image file format (and corresponding mime-type) received to the client must still be one of `png`, `jpg`, `gif` etc. as otherwise the browser / user-agent will not render/understand it.

So, I don't see how this would affect Google Search.

However, it could affect *Image Search* for the reasons you mention... none descriptive filename etc. But if the indexing of images is not a concern (and these are perhaps blocked from Googlebot-Image anyway) then I can't see that it is a problem.

> ...but inform spiders that it is relevant and contextual media related to the text content on the page.

Does Google look at the type/context of the images themselves when determining rank in Google Search?

Comment: Yes, images enhance on-page SEO — based on alt attribute, contextual placement, filename, etc.

Comment: Actually, modern browsers render `.ashx` files as images without any problems (see [image from Sitecore's official site](https://d1yow6fhovqcc2.cloudfront.net/~/media/Home/Customer%20Screenshots/carnival%20cruise%20homepage%20img.ashx?ts=120612020845496))

Comment: Yes, the `alt` text etc. certainly helps SEO, but the image itself? That image you link to is served as an ordinary `PNG` image.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say with the 1st part, perhaps you misunderstood? Anyway, the latter part of the image's filename is `carnival%20cruise%20homepage%20img.ashx`, and if you try [an image like this](http://media.sc.easyjet.com/ejcms/cache/medialibrary/Images/Standard%20Scrolling%20MultiFeature%20Banners/C%20Holidays/EN-EJ-HOLS-COUPLE-CITY-SMF.ashx), [this](http://www.cityandguilds.com/~/media/Images/About%20Us/Broadsheet%20News/May13/FisherSmall%20jpg.ashx) or [this](http://www.seas-nve.dk/~/media/NyForside/BottomStory/illuStoryRight.ashx) and download it — it'll still be `.ashx`

Comment: The first part... of my answer or the comment? The URL (or filename) that you quote, ending in `.ashx` is the URL of the resource requested from the server. This itself does not necessarily indicate the format of the file returned (there is no such thing as an `ashx` image file format) - if that is what you are implying? The last 3 images you link to are all jpegs, and this is indicated to the browser/spider by the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` HTTP response header. The mime-type is what indicates the type of the file and this is what the browser sees.

Comment: When you download/"save as" these images it will use the original URL of the requested resource as a filename _suggestion_, **unless** you also send a `Content-Disposition` header with an alternative filename, as in the first link you posted from Sitecore. But, as stated above, the filename does not necessarily indicate the file format.